Kotlin || Room DB : Exception while computing database live data
I have this app with Room DB and APIs. Some of the frequently used data from APIs is stored in Room DB along with every user's session
But here I'm getting this exception despite clear cache, clear data from app on device & invalidating cache on Android studio, cleaning build and rebuilding.
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while computing database live data.
  at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData.refreshRunnable$lambda$0 (RoomTrackingLiveData.kt:74)
  at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData.$r8$lambda$PhMGW5zFk4QWazERd2lfEeLZqW0
  at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1012)
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException:
  at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.checkIdentity (RoomOpenHelper.kt:146)
  at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onOpen (RoomOpenHelper.kt:127)
  at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onOpen (FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.kt:287)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:427)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:316)
  at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableOrReadableDatabase (FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.kt:232)
  at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.innerGetDatabase (FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.kt:190)
  at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getSupportDatabase (FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.kt:151)
  at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase (FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.kt:104)
  at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction (RoomDatabase.kt:632)
  at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction (RoomDatabase.kt:451)
  at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query (RoomDatabase.kt:480)
  at androidx.room.util.DBUtil.query (DBUtil.kt:75)
  at com.vivayag.app.source.database.RoomDao_Impl$27.call (RoomDao_Impl.java:847)
  at com.vivayag.app.source.database.RoomDao_Impl$27.call (RoomDao_Impl.java:843)
  at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData.refreshRunnable$lambda$0 (RoomTrackingLiveData.kt:72)

If an app is uninstalled from the device, it should clear the room db data and shouldn't begin with the last logged in User account on the next install of the app. Like by default the app flow is OnBoarding > Login Screen > Home Screen
But on this exception, the newly installed app goes straight to Home Screen with the same account credentials that were logged in last time (before uninstalling the app). After a second or two the Home screen crashes with this exception.

Can you provide code of the Database class and DAOs?

Please reproduce a brief example of your error. Or share more code so people can help.

did you up the version number to DB post code changes, ill suggest to start with that
